# hjkl habit breaking - soft version

Tags: vim

I've just read article about turning off `hjkl` to learn using other vim motions commands more efficiently.

This approach is a little too hardcore for me, so I'd like to setup some softer constraint to use the same motion key max 3 times in a row. How can I do this?

Comment: I want to upvote this because it shows how extensible vim can be, but at the same time your expectations on ready plugins are a little high (or maybe not?).

Comment: Oooh! Another victim of the "Don't use the arrows, use `hjkl`!" meme. If reading `:help motion.txt` and a bit of willpower is not enough to break your habit, nothing will.

Comment: @romainl, you're wrong. I don't use arrows at all, `hjkl` only, but often insted of ie. typing `)` I type `kkkkk`, it would be nice if somthing could remind me there is better option. And believe me, turning off arrows when I started using vim help me break 'arrow habit'.

Comment: No. I'm not wrong because I never said that you are using the arrows. But you *were* using the arrows and you successfully broke that habit by replacing it with another bad habit. That's why I said that you are a victim. You were told that the arrows are bad and that you should use `hjkl` instead but using `hjkl` is just as inefficient as the arrows and you find yourself trapped in a relatively worthless habit. You should have learned the other motions instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [mediummode plugin](https://github.com/kbarrette/mediummode); it (and the idea of a *hard mode*) have been mentioned on [the usevim site](http://usevim.com/2013/04/03/hardmode/).

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work the way I thought. It stops after for example: 'kl', and I think it's wrong. Should stop only after typing the same key twice in a row. Anyway, thanks for help, maybe I will learn vimcode and write it by my own.

Comment: Such a plugin would be hard to write for a complete beginner... but you could try submitting a feature request to the author of mediummode via GitHub!